# How to set max value length for div with attribute contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Actually there are some attributes for input fields...

One of these attributes is `maxlength` that denies the user to input more characters or numbers than specified.

**Is there a way to set a attribute like this to a div that has the property `contenteditable` ?**

Of course I could write a jquery or javascript function to get this done but I was wondering if there is a property like this.
And I think, it is not necessary to re-invent the wheel :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **NO**.  From the docs, maxlength only works for input type.

> The maxlength attribute specifies the maximum number of characters allowed in the `<input>` element.

You need to use some scripting language(like javascript and jquery which you already did) to make it work on contenteditable div.